# Error in python csv analyse script, permission error

Tags: python, csv, error-handling, permissions

I'm posting this question because I have an issue with my python script.
The goal of this script is to get a csv file and select all the line by the attribute 'year' and stock them in differente file.

```
import csv
import os

file=open("file_to_analyse.csv", encoding="utf8")
csv_file=csv.reader(file)

header = next(csv_file)

data_to_retr="annee"

def create_new_csv_file(new_csv_file_name, line):
    with open(new_csv_file_name+".csv", 'w'):
        print("file created ...")
    whitelist.append(new_csv_file_name)
    append_line_to_csv_file(line, new_csv_file_name)

def append_line_to_csv_file(line, target_file):
    path=target_file+".csv"
    assert os.path.isfile(path)
    with open(path, 'a', encoding='utf8') as out:
        out.write(str(line)+"\n")
        print("writting a line ...")

for i in range(len(header)):
    if header[i] == data_to_retr:
        target=i

whitelist = []

i=0

for line in csv_file:
    i=i+1
    print(i)
    if line[target] in whitelist:
        append_line_to_csv_file(line, line[target])
    else:
        create_new_csv_file(line[target], line)

print(whitelist)

print("--- Fin du travail ---")
```

The issue is that when I launch the script he works fine but after a while of work he crach with this error :
File "C:\Users\boite\OneDrive\Bureau\PTM_Slider\prog.py", line 71, in 
append_line_to_csv_file(line, line[target])
File "C:\Users\boite\OneDrive\Bureau\PTM_Slider\prog.py", line 55, in append_line_to_csv_file
with open(path, 'a', encoding='utf8') as out:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '1845.csv'

In this case I work with a csv file of 3 million of line.
You can borrow a example file here
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hadriengithub/CSV_SLIDER/main/file_to_analyse.csv

Have a good day

Comment: https://itsmycode.com/python-permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied/#:~:text=In%20Python%2C%20If%20we%20provide,Errno%2013%5D%20Permission%20denied%20error.

Comment: Without rewriting your script for you, I'd suggest that you add more debug with print()

It seems that you are trying to create a file for every "annee" that is in the csv.

Try printing the name of the file, as it is failing to create / append to it and returns permission errors